# Form Login with background-image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm doing a login access with bootstrapping. But he's not leaving me well. The problem is that I did not want to put position but I am obliged to do mess boxes within the image. I also, leaving space between 2 columns and would have to be together

---> [BOOTPLY CODE](http://www.bootply.com/9KeIzIAiwI)

Is there any way to do better ??

I attached the link bootply and image as it should be :(

[image: Must be like this]

Comment: Copy the smallest relevant markup here. Images are not acceptable.

Comment: simple make col-lg-6 and set offset. Then apply your other style

Comment: but position to put my 2 columns above the image? or is there another way? @webtuts4u

Comment: Set image as background, and then make cols & apply the css to set these positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to research more about bootstrap to learn how the structure works. Basically, you need a .container then under that a .row and then under that you can add your .cols. Your image should have been a background image as well.

I have reworked your bootply example here. http://www.bootply.com/5U5EwnYJyl

Cheers